# How to call IEnumerable

Tags: c#, types

I have a subroutine:

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> permutations<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    var c = source.Count();
    if (c == 1)
        yield return source;
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            foreach (var p in permutations(source.Take(i).Concat(source.Skip(i + 1))))
                yield return source.Skip(i).Take(1).Concat(p);
    }
```

Then how to call it in main function?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "abcdefghijk";
    IEnumerable<string> summary;
    summary= permutations<string>(IEnumerable<string> input);// obviously wrong, but how??
}
```

Comment: Given the disparate answers, perhaps you can comment on what you expect permutations() to return?  Do you want a collection of strings, collection of collection of characters, something else?  The collection you pass to permutations() will influence the return type.

Comment: I want to collect all strings, which are the permutation of the string.

Comment: @Love: What is the practical application of this function? Its hanging in my system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling the function is easy, you just need:

```
permutations(input)
```

This will give you a result that is a sequence of characters sequences.  To convert the inner `IEnumerable<char>` into strings just use `Select`.

```
summary = permutations(input).Select(chars => new string(chars.ToArray()));
```

Comment: No, there is an exception.cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>' to 'char[]'

Comment: @Love You must be on a version pre 4.0.  I will adjust the code accordingly.  If/when you upgrade to 4.0 the `ToArray` call can be omitted.

Comment: +1 Thank you! This is most correct answer as it addresses the caller's intent of using the function, and not just fixing the compilation error with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

```
summary = permutations(input);
```

Unless permutations is in a different class.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<char>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: The return type of Permutations is `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>>`, when passed a string.

Comment: @Love This is called just properly, you just aren't handling the results of the method properly

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot instantiate an `IEnumerable` directly, **you must pass in a class that implements this interface** (one popular choice is to use a `List` to hold the data).

The .NET framework will **automatically interpret a string as a character array** (`char[]`), which implements `IEnumerable` (i.e. `IEnumerable<char>`). This is why you can pass in your string directly into the method, like so:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "abcdefghijk";
    var summary = permutations(input);
}
```

The above code is shorthand for the more explicit version of what is happening, which can be described by the following code, which has a method call that explicitly matches the signature of the `permutations` method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "abcdefghijk";

    IEnumerable<char> inputArray = input.ToCharArray();

    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> summary = permutations(inputArray);
}
```

Comment: It is a string permutation, I want to print all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it in two ways:

```
permutations<char>(input);
```

or

```
permutations(input);
```

Second call uses **compiler type inference**, so you don't have to specify **T**.

And then:

```
        foreach (var outerEnumerator in permutations(test))
        {
            foreach (var singleChar in outerEnumerator)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(singleChar);
            }
        }
```

And version with explicit types & nice formating (each word in separate line):

```
        foreach (IEnumerable<char> outerEnumerator in permutations(test))
        {
            foreach (char singleChar in outerEnumerator)
            {
                Console.Write(singleChar);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

And now that we know what method is about to do:

```
        var test = "test";
        foreach (IEnumerable<char> testPermutation in permutations(test))
        {
            var permutationString = new string(testPermutation.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(permutationString);
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Simplest method is to create a List of `string`

```
List<string> strArr = new List<string>();
strArr.Add("firstItem");
strArr.Add("secondItem");
strArr.Add("thirdItem");
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> summary = permutations<string>(strArr);
```